# How to ensure webpage DOM is fully loaded before using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load a DOM of the currently open webpage in a Google Chrome extension app that I am developing and then retrieve some elements and store them in variables for manipulation. Currently, I am just trying to grab the sender email under the `gD` class for the specified span. As of now it will output whatever I have in the `doStuffWithDOM` function twice to the console. I have tried using several variations of ensuring that the page is fully loaded before calling the function like `tab.status==complete` or/and `changeInfo.status==complete` but it still calls the function multiple times. Any suggestions on how to ensure the webpages DOM is fully loaded before calling the `doStuffWithDOM` function?

```
background.js

function doStuffWithDOM(domContent) {
       senderName = $(domContent).find("span.gD");
       console.log(senderName);
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id,changeInfo,tab){
    if(changeInfo.status=='complete' && tab.status=='complete'){ //To send message after the webpage has loaded
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { text: "report_back" },function(response){
           doStuffWithDOM(response);
        });
    }
})
```

```
console output:

test
jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(62)]
test
jQuery.fn.init [span.gD, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(70)]
```

Comment: Use MutationObserver (or setInterval) in the content script to wait for the element.

Comment: So I am not using a content script would I just add that to the `background.js` file?

Comment: No, you need a content script.